# Pointing on vector elements

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers, vector

I've got a vector of objects (apples) and I need a pointer to jump through every element, to print "size" value on every object in "apples". I tried vector::iterator, pointing whole vector but I still cannot get correct solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Apple{
public:
    int size;
    Apple(int size): size(size){}
    void print(){
        std::cout<<size;
    }
};

    std::vector<Apple*>apples = {new Apple(21), new Apple(37), new Apple(66)}; 
    Apple* ptr = apples[0];

void nextApple(){
    ptr++;
    ptr->print(); //returns 0
}

int main()
{
    nextApple();
    return 0;
}
```

Big thank You for any help!

Comment: You have a vector of **pointers to** apples. You don't need that. Just use `std::vector<Apple>`.

Comment: In general, [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate through any `T[]` array using a pointer, you need to use a `T*` pointer, and you need to point it initially at the *address* of the 1st element, not the *value* of the element.

Your `vector`'s element type is `T = Apple*`, not `T = Apple`, so you need to use an `Apple**` pointer rather than an `Apple*` pointer, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Apple{
public:
    int size;
    Apple(int size) : size(size){}
    void print(){
        std::cout << size << std::endl;
    }
};

std::vector<Apple*> apples = {new Apple(21), new Apple(37), new Apple(66)}; 
Apple** ptr = &apples[0];

void nextApple(){
    ++ptr;
    (*ptr)->print();
}

int main()
{
    nextApple();
    return 0;
}
```

Using an iterator instead (or even an index) would have worked just fine, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Apple{
public:
    int size;
    Apple(int size): size(size){}
    void print(){
        std::cout << size << std::endl;
    }
};

std::vector<Apple*> apples = {new Apple(21), new Apple(37), new Apple(66)}; 
std::vector<Apple*>::iterator iter = apples.begin();
// or: size_t index = 0;

void nextApple(){
    ++iter;
    (*iter)->print();

    // or:
    // ++index;
    // apples[index]->print();
}

int main()
{
    nextApple();
    return 0;
}
```

---

That being said, using a `vector` of raw `Apple*` pointers is not a good idea.  You have to `delete` the `Apple` objects when you are done using them. At the very least, you should wrap the pointers in `std::unique_ptr` to avoid memory leaks, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Apple{
public:
    int size;
    Apple(int size): size(size){}
    void print(){
        std::cout << size << std::endl;
    }
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Apple>> apples = {std::make_unique<Apple>(21), std::make_unique<Apple>(37), std::make_unique<Apple>(66)}; 
auto *ptr = &apples[0];
// or: auto iter = apples.begin();
// or: size_t index = 0;

void nextApple(){
    ++ptr;
    (*ptr)->print();

    // or:
    // ++iter;
    // (*iter)->print();

    // or:
    // ++index;
    // apples[index]->print();
}

int main()
{
    nextApple();
    return 0;
}
```

But really, just get rid of the dynamic allocation altogther, you don't need it in this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Apple{
public:
    int size;
    Apple(int size): size(size){}
    void print(){
        std::cout << size << std::endl;
    }
};

std::vector<Apple> apples = {21, 37, 66}; 
Apple* ptr = &apples[0];
// or: auto iter = apples.begin();
// or: size_t index = 0;

void nextApple(){
    ++ptr;
    ptr->print();

    // or:
    // ++iter;
    // iter->print();

    // or:
    // ++index;
    // apples[index].print();
}

int main()
{
    nextApple();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question is not idiomatic C++; more like a Java design. In C++ iterators just work:

```
void show_apples() {
    std::vector<Apple> apples =
        { Apple(21), Apple(37), Apple(66) };
    for (auto iter = apples.begin(); iter != Apples.end(); ++iter)
        std::cout << iter->size << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```